# mysql-connector-j vs mysql-connector-java maven dependency differences

Tags: java, maven, mysql-connector

What is difference between these two Maven dependencies for connecting to MySQL DB:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is the same: *MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.*

Comment: The second one is the correct/current one. The first one is outdated. It will be updated on Maven but for a limited time only. Check here: https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-connectorj-has-new-maven-coordinates

Comment: Here is the blog describing the reasons.
https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-connectorj-has-new-maven-coordinates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR

**Use this**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

MySQL renamed the connector:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html

You should use **MySQL Connector/J**.

---

If you are using the **Spring-Boot-3.0** or above then you should use **MySQL Connector/J**.

> *The coordinates of the MySQL JDBC driver have changed from mysql:mysql-connector-java to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j. If you are
> using the MySQL JDBC driver, update its coordinates accordingly when
> upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.*

[*Source*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#mysql-jdbc-driver)

---

Also from the comment @Mar-Z provided this information:

> The second one is the correct/current one. The first one is outdated.
> It will be updated on Maven but for a limited time only. Check here: [MySQL Connector/J has new Maven Coordinates](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-connectorj-has-new-maven-coordinates)